# AWS Cognito User pool Forgot Password with Google Captcha

Tags: amazon-web-services, recaptcha, amazon-cognito, forgot-password

We want to implement Cognito User pool: Forgot Password feature on the Angular Web APP by asking to validate using Google Captcha. Upon doing research we found that Forgot password API doesn't support custom parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html

Is it possible to UserContextData field for this?

In web App we are using aws-amplify and it doesn't seem to support it:
https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/authentication_guide.html#forgot-password

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: found any solutions?